# How to add real Loading Screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have an android application of a pdf file inside. When I open my application on lower configuration devices (galaxy 2 etc.), it takes a while to load the PDF file. I tried to adding a splash screen in my application but when opening `MainActivity.class` after `SplashScreen` still taking same time. How can I develop a real loading screen? It should work on top of `Main Activity` layer.
**Here my codes:**

> **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

> **SplashScreen.class**

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GifImageView gifImageView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        gifImageView=(GifImageView)findViewById(R.id.gifview);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(progressBar.VISIBLE);

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("loading.gif");
            byte[] bytes  = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            gifImageView.setBytes(bytes);
            gifImageView.startAnimation();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                    Intent intent = newIntent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                    SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
                    SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }
        },12000);
    }
}
```

**Here my codes how I can solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Async Task for this?
You can use the async task in your MainActivity.

For Example you can do something like the following:

```
class PDFLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    protected void onPreExecute (){
        super.onPreExecute();
       // Here you can instantiate the Progressdialog to show the progress.

    }
    protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {
        // here you can go ahead write the reading logic for the PDF
       // if it is taking time.
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...a){
        super.onProgressUpdate(a);
       // you may or may not use this. This can act as a progress updated based on
       // the integer.
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Here you can dismiss the progress bar since the read as been done.
    }
}
```

Call it like this in your MainActivity:

```
new PDFLoader().execute();
```

I hope this helps you. 
This is just the basic structure to get you started. More information [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: How i can do that? here my MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Splash screen is not a solution to this.You are adding a screen with 12second gap and after 12 second the MainActivity class is getting execute.
So, you can directly add a progress bar in MainActivity class and you can use **AsyncTask** to solve this problem.
AsyncTask has 3 methods-
OnPreExecute, doInBackground, OnPostExecute. Here, you can add a progress bar in OnPreExecute method and the code for opening PDF file in doInBackground method, and finally stop the progress bar in OnPostExecute method.

For more help you should provide your **MainActivity** class code here.

Comment: "Using a Splash screen is not a solution to this." - why? There could be splash activity, all time consuming tasks could be executed in splash activity (with AsyncTask), after async task finished, splash activity needs to be finished and main acttivity launched - if neccesary, pass some task results with bundle to main acttivity.

Comment: Yes you can pass bundle.. that's exactly same if you will do all this in MainActivity. Using an activity in between seems no point. In addition to this the question asked above requires solution on **top of MainActivity layer** so i think this is much better solution

Comment: It's not exactly the same actually. You could create SplashActivity without any layout (only background set via style). It will load super fast, because of no need to inflate any layout. Note that splash screen should always appear without any lag, this is important especially on slower devices

Comment: Yeah now this will be Cool...you can follow any of above..i think both will work correctly..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **LoadingScreen** instead of splash screen(looking at your 12 secs. delay). Here is something that might help:

```
public class LoadingScreen {private ImageView loading;

LoadingScreen(ImageView loading) {
this.loading = loading;
}

public void setLoadScreen(){
final Integer[] loadingImages = {R.mipmap.loading_1, R.mipmap.loading_2, 
R.mipmap.loading_3, R.mipmap.loading_4};
final Handler loadingHandler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    int loadingImgIndex = 0;
    public void run() {
        loading.setImageResource(loadingImages[loadingImgIndex]);
        loadingImgIndex++;
        if (loadingImgIndex >= loadingImages.length)
            loadingImgIndex = 0;
        loadingHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);//change to accordingly(i.e. 12000)
    }
};
loadingHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 500); // change it accordingly
}}
```

In your MainActivity, you can pass a to the LoadingScreen class like this :-

```
private ImageView loadingImage;
```

Don't forget to add an ImageView in activity_main. After that call the LoadingScreen class like this;

```
 LoadingScreen loadingscreen = new LoadingScreen(loadingImage);
loadingscreen.setLoadScreen();
```

It is always helpful in creating a custom loading screen instead of Splash screen.Also don't forget to add some different images to make that feel like a **gif** and after that add the images in the `res` folder . I have checked it for lower versions too Therefore, believe that it might serve your purpose...

Comment: Have you added **gif** in your res folder

Comment: Yes I have mentioned in the answer about it

Comment: You are certainly doing something wrong?Are you adding a set of images to `res` folder

Answer (score 0):

You should give a shot to this article: https://antonioleiva.com/branded-launch-screen/
It's far better than Splash Screen, 'cause It loads async to your MainActivity

Add this code to styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
   <style name="AppTheme.BrandedLaunch" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/branded_logo</item>
   </style>
```

Now create branded_logo.xml into your drawable directory

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/background_material_light"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/launch_logo_image"
            android:tileMode="disabled"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And assign that style into your MainActivity

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.BrandedLaunch">
```

And finally add setStyle to your default theme in your onCreate in MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
```

Comment: Don't come up with the links in the answer as links will be unavailable at times.Do write the code in the answer instead

Comment: Have you set MainActivity as your Launcher Activity after your tried this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays lots of applications are avoiding loading screen due to bad UI/UX.  You can use alternative for content loading. This [article](http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/stop-using-loading-spinner-theres-something-better/) may help more about. You can look this kind of implementation on lot of popular apps like Facebook, LinkedIn, Upwork etc.